# Protractor browser.sleep() is not getting executed

Tags: protractor

In the below as you can see that the browser.sleep is supposed to be executed if the client is XYZ, but still it is not getting executed.

If i put any console.log after the browser.sleep statement, that statement is getting executed (i can see the statement) but the browser.sleep is not really waiting even though how much the sleep time i increase.

Why is the browser.sleep is not working? How do i make it wait if the client XYZ?

```
           if (testproperties.client == 'ABC'){
                browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
                browser.waitForAngular();
                browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;    
            }
            else if (testproperties.client == 'XYZ'){
                browser.sleep('35000');
            };
```

Comment: Here is the documentation for sleep. http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.sleep you are supposed to pass a number

Answer (score 12):

Do you passing int type as parameter? Seems like it is string. Try

```
browser.sleep(35000)
```

Also check why you might need such huge browser sleep? Maybe you want `browser.wait()` instead?

Answer (score 2):

put await in front of **browser** and pass a parameter to sleep (time in ms).

```
await browser.sleep(5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try resolving the promise.

```
browser.sleep(35000).then(
  function(){
     console.log("Waiting");
  }
)
```

Or update protractor to the last version

```
npm install protractor@latest --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following answer.

```
if (testproperties.client == 'ABC'){
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    browser.driver.sleep(2000);
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;    
}
else if (testproperties.client == 'XYZ'){
    browser.driver.sleep(2000);
};
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Happy to help. If u got the ryt answer, please accept it. so, others can easily find the answer. thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please give it a try with below code sample .

```
//For none angular sites
 browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

//browser.get('url');
//If normal browser.sleep(7000); didnt work try
browser.driver.sleep(8000);
//click using ID instead of Javasctipt
 element(by.id('next')).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you launch protractor with `headless` parameter `browser.sleep()` cannot works.

Remove this parameter and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

browser.sleep() should be executed with sync mode instead of async